# reading many records for one user id

Tags: php, mysqli

I create relation between two tables (login_pre , privilege ) 
and many accesslevel for one user id
they are as follows:

privilege table:

```
+----------------------------------+
|  AccessLevel | login_id  | pre_id|
|----------------------------------|
|      1       |    1     |   1    |
|      2       |    1     |   2    | 
|      4       |    2     |   4    |
+----------------------------------+
```

and this is login_pre table:

```
    +----------------------------------+
    |  username| userpass | login_id   |
    |----------------------------------|
    |      a   |    123   |   1        |
    |      a   |    123   |   1        | 
    |      b   |   1234   |   2        |
    +----------------------------------+
```

**where admin who add accesslevel**

how can I create php code that read right many record for one user id

I try this code many times but it output nothing

```
   $query ="SELECT * 
FROM privilege AS privilege.login_id 
JOIN login_pre AS login_pre.login_id 
ON privilege.login_id=login_pre.login_id ";//output nothing
```

then I try :

```
$query =
        "SELECT * 
        FROM privilege 
        where login_id='".$_SESSION['sessionloginid']."'  " ;
```

output as follows:

in privilege page:

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['sessionloginid']))// point to id of user logged in
        {  
        $query =
        "SELECT * 
        FROM privilege 
        where login_id='".$_SESSION['sessionloginid']."'  " ;
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('');
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {


             $_SESSION['sessionloginid']= $row['login_id']; //output 11
           $_SESSION['sessionaccess']= $row['AccessLevel'];//output 12

                }
        }
```

and protect page:

```
function protect_page()


{


    if($_SESSION['sessionloginid']== true && $_SESSION['sessionaccess'] !=1 )

    {
//header ('location:http://localhost/database/agtdatabase/agt_site/agtSite/agt2.php');
 //$_SESSION['sessionloginid']; // output 1  
 echo $_SESSION['sessionaccess'] ;//output 2 only for user loginid = 1 =>the problem
exit();             

    }
}
protect_page();
```

side note I wrote this question before and follow answer but it outputs nothing and no reply after that so I write question more clear what I want 
a code to reading  right many records for single user

Comment: You have a bizarre privileges setup that is probably what’s causing your problems. You’d be better of creating pre-defined “roles” that each have privileges, and then associating a user with a role, independent of privileges.

Comment: I think your answer is the best solution ..but I'm beginner in this and follow tutorials what is pre-defined rules

Answer (score 0):

```
$query ="SELECT privilege1.AccessLevel 
FROM privilege AS privilege1 
JOIN login_pre AS login_pre1
ON privilege1.login_id=login_pre1.login_id ";
```

Comment: I edit it but output of accesslevel=4 for user id 1 strange output

Answer (score 0):

There are errors on your query. Take a look here:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM privilege
JOIN login_pre
ON privilege.login_id=login_pre.login_id";
```

Comment: When you do, for example, "privilege AS privilege.login_id", "privilege.login_id" points to the table name, not the "login_id" field. This should give you a SQL syntax error. AS is used only to create aliases to the table (in this case), not point to the table fields. The first thing is, then, remove the ".login_id" from both aliases. The aliases aren't necessary, so I removed them from my example. At "ON" clause, you can access your fields to compare them.